# append child inner html?

Tags: javascript, append, innerhtml, appendchild

I have set up a function where I click a button and want to append html to an empty div on my page, not sure why it isn't working, I am getting the results 1 console log.

```
document.getElementById("results2").onclick = function(){
        var total = w + x + y + z ;
        console.log(total);

        if (total == 4 || total == 5 || total == 6) {
            console.log("results1");

            function () {
                var div1 = document.createElement('div');

                div1.className = 'row';

                div1.innerHTML = '<p>chillwave</p>';

                document.getElementById('resultstitle').appendChild(div1);
}
        }

         if (total == 7 || total == 8 || total == 9) {
            console.log("results2");
        }

         if (total == 10 || total == 11 || total == 12) {
            console.log("results3");
        }

    }
```

Comment: Why do you put the code which appends the div inside of a `function()` ?

Comment: lol I don't know but i took it out and that fixed it thank!